# Jenkins + PowerShell - Converting Zip File to Bytes, Transfer Bytes, Then Reconstruct Bytes to Zip

Tags: powershell, jenkins, converters, file-transfer

As this complex problem now has a viable solution, I wanted to update this to accommodate the solution so that others can benefit from this.

#### Problem

I am working with Jenkins and PowerShell to perform a series of actions. One such action is to gather up and consolidate all associate log files into a single folder named accordingly to associate it with the originating machine/server, zip the folder up, transfer it back to the Jenkins workspace environment somehow, store the zips into a single master folder, and convert said master folder into an artifact which can be downloaded at a later time/date for debugging. However, since this action tends to involve the two-hop exchange, I have hit a number of walls that have inhibited my ability to perform simple file transfers. So I am turning to the community to seek assistance from those who hopefully have more experience doing this kind of thing.

The only way (that I have found so far) for me to perform many of the actions I need is to connect to the target machine through an `Invoke-Command` ; however, it did not take long for me to start running into walls. One such wall being the issues with file transfer between Jenkins and the target machine. I have found that by creating an object that equals the invoked command ( ex: `$returnMe = Invoke-Command {}` ), I am able to return objects from the action to be stored in the variable. This has given me a possible resolution to the problem of returning an item to Jenkins through the session... but now brings forward the question:

#### Question

1. Using PowerShell, is it possible to zip a folder up, then convert
   that zip file into an object to be passed, and then reconstruct that
   zip file using the contents of the object? If so, how?

#### Resolution:

A special shout out to @ArcSet for assistance in getting this to work right.

Alright, so it is extremely possible to do this; however, it takes a series of key steps to make it happen. One such thing that this is a four to five step process:

1) Gather the files into the target folder and zip the folder
2) Convert the zip file into bytes that can be easily transfered
3) Pass those byte through a special custom object
4) Parse the object to ensure excess bytes did not find their way into the file.
5) Convert the bytes back into a zip file on Jenkins

Below is the code (with comments) that shows how this was achieved:

```
# Parse Through Each Server One By One
ForEach ($server in $servers) {
    # Create a Variable to Take in the Invoke-Command and Receive what is Returned
    $packet = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ArgumentList $server -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock {
        # Function for Creating a Zip File
        Function Create-ZipFromFolder ([string]$Source, [string]$SaveAs) {
            Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
            [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, $SaveAs)
        }

        # Function for Converting Zip to Bytes For File Transfer
        Function Get-BytesFromFile($Path) {
            return [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($Path)
        }

        # Absorb and Maske Server IP for the Server to Use For Logging Purposes and FileNaming
        $maskedAddress = $args[0] -Replace ('.+(?=\.\d+$)', 'XX.XX.XX')

        # Construct the Path For Consolidated Log Files
        $masterLogFolderPath = ("C:\Logs\RemoteLogs\$maskedAddress")

        # Series of Code to Create Log Folder, Consolidate Files, And Delete Unnecessary Data For Cleanup

        # Establish what to Save the Zip As. You Will Want The Path Included to Prevent it From Finding Path of Least Resistance Upon Saving
        $zipFile = ($masterLogFolderPath + ".zip")

        Try {
           # Here is Where We Call Our Compression Function
           Create-ZipFromFolder -Source $masterLogFolderPath -SaveAs ZipFile

           # Next We Convert the Zip to Bytes
           [byte[]]$FileAsBytes = Get-BytesFromFile -Path $zipFile
        }
        Catch {
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        }

        # Now We Return the New Object to Jenkins
        return New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{Response=$FileAsBytes}
    }

    # Function to Convert the Bytes Back Into a Zip File
    Function Create-FileFromBytes([byte[]]$Bytes, [string]$SaveAs) {
        # It was Discovered that Depending Upon the Environment, Extra Bytes Were Sometimes Added
        # These Next Lines Will Help to Remove Those
        For (($k = 0), ($kill = 0); $kill -lt 1; $k++) {
            If ($Bytes[$k] -gt 0) {
                $kill = 1
                # Truncate the Excess Bytes
                $newByteArray = ($Bytes)[$k..(($Bytes).Length -1)]
            }
        }

        # Reconstruct the Zip File
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($SaveAs, $NewByteArray)
    }

    Try {
        # Call the Function to Begin Reconstruction
        Create-FileFromBytes -SaveAs "$env:Workspace\MasterLog\$maskedAddress.zip" -Bytes $packet.response
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
    }
```

Now this is just a base skeleton without all the heavy stuff, but these are the key pieces that put everything together. For the most part, following this formula will return the desired results. I hope this helps others who find themselves in a similar situation.

Thank you all again for your assistance

Comment: 1) You could read the zip file as a byte array and then export that. Or you could `Get-Content | Out-File` each individual log file into the workspace then zip. But... Personally I would try to solve the file transfer issue. `Copy-Item` from the machine to the workspace will be a whole lot cleaner.

Comment: @BenH I tried dozens of ways to get `Copy-Item` to work through Jenkins; however, I ran into many walls. 1) While inside an `Invoke-Command`, PowerShell loses scope of the Jenkins Workspace, 2) Due to the current stage that the PowerShell plugin is at, `Copy-Item` does not support `To/From-Session` , 3) Due to the work environment, I cannot use PowerShell on those machines to talk to an IP Address; the list goes on. As much as I wanted `Copy-Item` to do what it was designed for, it just wasn't in the stars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first you will need to create a zip file.
You will need to load the assembly system first by using **add-type**.
Use the **CreateFromDirectory** method to build and save the zip file.
Use the **System.IO.File** class to read all the bytes from the zip. At this point you can send this data to another computer. Finally use the **System.IO.File** class to turn the byte array back into a file

```
function Create-ZipFromFrolder([string]$Source,[string]$SaveAs){
    Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
    [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, $SaveAs)
    return $SaveAs
}

function Get-BytesFromFile([string]$File){
    return [byte[]]$ZipFileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($File)
}

function Create-FileFromBytes([byte[]]$Bytes, [string]$SaveAs){
    return [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($SaveAs, $Bytes)
}

[byte[]]$FileAsBytes = Get-BytesFromFile -File (Create-ZipFromFrolder -Source "C:\ZipFolder" -SaveAs "C:\Test\test.zip")

Create-FileFromBytes -SaveAs "C:\ZipFolder\Test.zip" -Bytes $FileAsBytes
```

Comment: I am getting an error stating that "**Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Empty path name is not legal.**". Was there a step that was missed? I noticed that in the function `Get-BytesFromFile` it takes in a parameter of `$File` but uses the variable `$destination` without showing where that variable is coming from

Comment: yup that was probably the issue with when u ran it

Comment: I got past the empty path issues but now it tells me that there is an issue converting to bytes: "Cannot Convert "C:\zip\file\path" with value type of "Deserialized.System.IO.DirectoryInfo" to type "System.Byte". Have you seen this before? I can't find anything about this error. It is encountered when running `Create-FileFromBytes`

Comment: did you name a file...becuase it looks like u named a folder

Comment: Hmm... No, doing it this way (returning the `$SaveAs` in the Create-ZipFromFolder ) causes it to see the folder and not the file when it tries to convert it to Bytes. So it fails earlier. If I break up the `Get-BytesFromFile` and `Create-ZipFromFolder` into separate actions, I can instead pass the direct path into the `Get-BytesFromFile` , which seems to let it work. However, when I try to place both of those inside the `$FileAsBytes = Invoke-Command { }` and then try to use the `Create-FileFromBytes` using that variable as the `-Bytes` it fails telling me that I'm providing a directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153895/discussion-between-brandon-and-arcset).